# Ajax форма reset

Tags: javascript, ajax

Насколько я понимаю, trigger("reset") должен очищать поля формы, после отправки. Почему этого не происходит ?

```
$("#form").submit(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "mail.php",
        data: $(this).serialize()
    }).done(function() {
        $(this).find("input").val("");
        alert("DZIĘKUJEMY! Twój numer został do nas wysłany. Wkrótce do 
  Ciebie zadzwonimy.");
        $("#form").trigger("reset");

    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: `$("#form")[0].reset();`

Comment: благодарю вас )